# Can I use the atto editor for my website?

Tags: moodle, text-editor

Atto editor is an editor built specifically for moodle. It has the option to pick images from my own personal computer instead of choosing an image from the server.
Can I use this editor for my website? If yes, then how?

I have tried using tinyMCE and CKeditor but the image browsing function was not working. I have the atto editor plugin installed but it doesnt seem to work. Nothing much is available on the net for atto editor as a standalone, it is used in moodle only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atto was written for Moodle and is designed entirely to work within Moodle. It may be possible to rewrite it to work independently of Moodle, but I'm guessing it would be quite a lot of work to do so.

Comment: I just want the functionality to add images from my local computer instead of having to supply a URL for images on the net or the server. What can I use?

Comment: You may struggle to find a standalone text editor that will support that 'out of the box', because uploading files from your local computer requires your server to process and store the file, so that it can be returned to the user viewing the generated text. A client-side editor cannot do that without some sort of server-side support for the upload.

Comment: Thanks for that knowledge :)